# keep data in codeigniter without flash data

Tags: php, codeigniter

I created a management system in codeigniter that loads data from the database in datatables for specific suppliers. When the user clicks at any of these data rows he is navigating to each supplier's company products. My problem is that I want to find a session or something else that will keep the data of the previous selected rows when the page reloads. At the moment I am using flashdata but when I go back a step or return to the previous page all the data from the database disappear. What I want is something that will keep my data even if I am reloading the page or if I go back a step.
That's my controller:

```
  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
     $this->load->model('dash_match_model');
     $this->session->keep_flashdata('supplier_id');
     $this->session->keep_flashdata('segment');
     $this->session->keep_flashdata('class');
      $this->session->keep_flashdata('commodity');
     $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->helper('url');

}

public function index() {
   $arr['page']='dash1';
   $user_id = $this->session->userdata('id');

   $supplier = $this->dash_match_model->dash_present_all_suppliers($user_id);
   $arr['dash_present_all_suppliers'] = $supplier;
    $this->load->view('clients/clDashboard',$arr);

}

public function select_supplier() 
{

    $supplier_name = $this->input->get('name', TRUE);


    $supplier_sel = $this->dash_match_model->selected_supplier_id($supplier_name);
    foreach ($supplier_sel->result() as $row){

        $this->session->set_flashdata('supplier_id', $row->supplier_id);
    }

    $selected_supplier = $this->dash_match_model->unspsc_matched_skus($this->session->flashdata('supplier_id'));
    $arr['dash_present_all_selected_suppliers'] = $selected_supplier;

    $this->load->view('clients/unspscSegment', $arr);
}

public function select_segment(){
    $segment = $this->input->get('segment', TRUE);
    $supplier_id = $this->session->flashdata('supplier_id');

    $this->session->set_flashdata('segment', $segment);
    $segment_sel =$this->session->flashdata('segment');

$selected_segment = $this->dash_match_model->unspsc_class($supplier_id, $segment_sel);

    $arr['dash_present_all_selected_segments'] = $selected_segment;

    $this->load->view('clients/unspscClass', $arr);

}

public function select_class(){
    $class = $this->input->get('class', TRUE);
    $supplier_id = $this->session->flashdata('supplier_id');
    $segment_sel =$this->session->flashdata('segment');

    $this->session->set_flashdata('class', $class);
    $class_sel = $this->session->flashdata('class');

    $selected_class =$this->dash_match_model->unspsc_commodity($supplier_id, $segment_sel, $class_sel);

    $arr['dash_present_all_selected_class'] = $selected_class;

    $this->load->view('clients/unsspscCommodity', $arr);
```

That's one of my first table view file with suppliers:

```
            <div class="row-fluid sortable">        
            <div class="box span12">
                <div class="box-header" data-original-title>
                    <div class="box-icon">
                        <a href="#" class="btn-setting"><i class="halflings-icon wrench"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn-minimize"><i class="halflings-icon chevron-up"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn-close"><i class="halflings-icon remove"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box-content">
                    <table id="suppliertable" class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable">
                      <thead>
                          <tr>
                              <th>Supplier</th>
                              <th>Open Range</th>
                              <th>Fill Content</th>
                              <th>Total Match</th>
                          </tr>
                      </thead>   
                      <tbody>
                      <?php foreach($dash_present_all_suppliers as $v): ?>
                              <tr>      
                                    <td class="center" style="color:#0c595b;"><a href="<?php  echo base_url(); ?>admin/dashboard1/select_supplier?name=<?php echo $v['supplierCompany']?>"><?php echo $v['supplierCompany']?> </a> </td>
                                    <td class="center">70%</td>
                                    <td class="center">12%</td>
                                    <td class="center">82%</td>
                            </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>  
                </div>
            </div><!--/span-->

        </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried temp data, instead of flash data? http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#tempdata You can set an expiry time for the session.

Comment: flahdata is unlinked on page refresh i.e. on new request made

Comment: @Craig I haven't tried temp_data. I will try it and let you know if that works. So by setting specific expiration time do you think that it will  keep the selected data of the previous table when I linked in to another?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `$this->session->flashdata()` user the normal session i.e. `$this->session->userdata()` to store the temp browse data and write a cron which will delete this session in a regular interval or at the time of logout or any desired specific action.

Hope this will give better approach n help you in solving your problem

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using $this->session->userdata()  when a  particular user logs into my system. How could I use that for the selected data of each table? I thought that this->session->userdata is used mostly for the login in the system.

Comment: session is used to store temporary data tough you use flashdata which is actually store data into session and on page refresh it deletes it if you go the system library of flashdata you will get a clear idea.
so its wise to use `session->userdata()` in your case.